# What kind of grammar is int& b = (&a)[15]

Tags: c++

```
int a = 30;
int& b = (&a)[15];
std::cout << b << std::endl;
```

I print it , find that this is a random value that doesn't make any sense

Comment: What is `a`?    That is rather key information.

Comment: If `a` is a `const int`, then (assuming your code even compiles, which is not guaranteed) `b` is a reference to contents of memory that - as far as your program is concerned - does not exist.    Almost every possible usage of `b`, including printing its value, then gives undefined behaviour.   Printing a nonsense value is one possible outcome of undefined behaviour.   So is reformatting your hard drive.

Comment: with `int a;`, `(&a)[15]` is out of bound access, so UB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What kind of grammar is int& b = (&a)[15]

`int& b` is a variable. Its name is `b` and its type is reference to int. `type variable_name = expression` is syntax for defining and initialising a variable.

`&` is a unary operator. For fundamental types, it is the addressof operator. Thus `&a` gives the address of the object referred by `a`. `[]` is the subscript operator. It adds the integer operand to the pointer operand, and indirects through the resulting pointer. In this case the pointer operand is a pointer to `a`, so the result is a reference to the fifteenth sibling of `a`. `b` is initialised to refer to that sibling.

---

Edit:

> ```
> int a = 30;
> ```

Given this context, there is no fiftheenth sibling, and so the behaviour of the program is undefined.